# Mysqli_query in php function

Tags: php, mysqli

First time I use php function.

All my mysli_query in function don't work.

In the same page the other mysqli_query work.

I don't understand why this doesn't work :

```
<?

function Afficher_Miniature($Miniature_Prod_id)
{  
    $req_Miniature_Prod = mysqli_query($base,"SELECT * FROM Produit WHERE Prod_id = '$Miniature_Prod_id'");
    $myrow_Miniature_Prod = mysqli_fetch_array($req_Miniature_Prod);
          
    $Miniature_Prod_Nom = $myrow_Miniature_Prod['Prod_Nom'];

    echo "<div>patati patata";
    echo $Miniature_Prod_Nom;
    echo "</div>";
}

Afficher_Miniature(26);
?>
```

The result is "patati patata"

Comment: `$base` is not available in the scope of your function. Use `global $base;` or pass `$base` to the function as a parameter.

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "don't work"? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You're using **mysqli_fetch_array** instead of **mysqli_fetch_assoc**.  The array version reads your row into an array with numerical indexes, not the field names as key.

fetch_assoc is your friend.